# Searching for the first prior non-weekend and non-holiday date in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to automate my analysis code which is run every weekday using the prior date as the end-date of the analysis unless that date falls on a weekend or a holiday.

My approach is to evaluate each date to determine if the prior day falls on a weekend or a local holiday. If the date is okay, then return that date as a vector for my analysis. If not, then find the next prior non-weekend or non-holiday date.

As an example, if I ran my code on July 5, 2022, the prior day (July 4) is a holiday, and the two days before that are weekend days. Therefore, I would like R to return the first non-holiday non-weekend date, which in this case is July 1, 2022.

I have written code that can evaluate whether the date is valid or not, but how to return the first valid date is a problem for me.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


# a list of holiday dates for 2022
holidays <- as.Date(c(NewYears = "2022-01-01", 
                      MLK = "2022-02-17", 
                      Presidents = "2022-02-21", 
                      CesarChavez = "2022-03-31",
                      Memorial = "2022-05-30",
                      Juneteenth = "2022-06-20",
                      Independence = "2022-07-04",
                      Labor = "2022-09-05",
                      Indigenous = "2022-10-10",
                      Veterans = "2022-11-11",
                      Thanksgiving = "2022-11-24",
                      DayAfterThanksGiving = "2022=11-25",
                      Christmas = "2022-12-26"
))

# set end date as yesterday's date (as an example)
mydate <- as.Date("2022-07-05") - 1

# determine if mydate is valid (non-holiday or weekend)
valid <- weekdays(mydate, abbreviate = TRUE) %in% as.character(c("Sat", "Sun")) |
  weekdays(mydate, abbreviate = TRUE) %in% holidays
```

If valid is FALSE, I would like R to keep going back until mydate is valid. A guess at a solution is to keep substrating days from mydate until valid becomes TRUE. But unsure how to code this iterative solution. Other approaches or suggestions on how to manage this problem are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option using a while loop:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)



# a list of holiday dates for 2022
holidays <- as.Date(c(NewYears = "2022-01-01", 
                      MLK = "2022-02-17", 
                      Presidents = "2022-02-21", 
                      CesarChavez = "2022-03-31",
                      Memorial = "2022-05-30",
                      Juneteenth = "2022-06-20",
                      Independence = "2022-07-04",
                      Labor = "2022-09-05",
                      Indigenous = "2022-10-10",
                      Veterans = "2022-11-11",
                      Thanksgiving = "2022-11-24",
                      DayAfterThanksGiving = "2022=11-25",
                      Christmas = "2022-12-26"
))

mydate <- as.Date("2022-07-05") - 1

# create function that returns TRUE/FALSE for valid status
valid_check <- function(mydate) {
  case_when(weekdays(mydate, abbreviate = TRUE) %in% c("Sat", "Sun") ~ FALSE, 
            mydate %in% holidays ~ FALSE, 
            TRUE ~ TRUE)
}

# loop through dates until a valid date is found and return the date
return_date <- function(mydate) {
  status <- valid_check(mydate)
  
  while(status == FALSE) {
    mydate <- mydate - 1
    status <- valid_check(mydate)
  }
  return(mydate)
}
```

Then you can run:

```r
return_date(mydate)
[1] "2022-07-01"
```